# Maximum number of different decimal digits in $p/q$ for $p , q \in \Bbb Z$.

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

In one of my class notes it was written that maximum number of different decimal digits in $p/q$ where $p , q \in \Bbb Z$ , is '$q$'. I don't know whether it is true or false, please tell me if it is correct or wrong with appropriate reason.

Comment: Maybe you mean "number of different digits after the ."? And if you do, you only need to check it for $q=1,\dots,9$ since otherwise the statement is trivial

Comment: There is a big difference between "Maximum number of different digits" and "length of the minimal period". You seem to be asking about the former, but I would think it is the latter that is actually the most interesting.

Comment: I've got a sneaking suspicion that the intended question is: "Prove that the repeating part of the decimal expansion of any rational number $ \frac{p}{q}\ $ has at most q digits." Or maybe it's q-1 digits.

Answer (score 2):

As stated the result is false since $\frac{246}{2}=123$ has $3$ digits.

For the number of digits after the decimal point, the result is true.

Since there are only $10$ digits we only need check $1\le q\le 9$. For $1,2,4,5,8$ the result is obvious.

The 'trickiest' case is $q=7$ but even without using a result such as Fermat's little theorem to prove your result neatly you only need check with a pocket calculator that each of $\frac{1}{7}, \frac{2}{7},..,\frac{6}{7}$ has precisely $6$ different digits.

Comment: sorry for , i made a mistake in body of my question . Actually my question implies , if the value of p/q is in decimals , then the maximum number of different digits after the decimal point will be 'q'.